# How to fix executing awk in Tcl?

Tags: awk, tcl

I am unable to read fields from `awk` command in Tcl while it runs in a terminal but not in Tcl script.

Tried making syntax changes, it works in terminal not in script

```
set a { A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z }

#store only cell var in file
exec grep -in "cell (?*" ./slow.lib | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 > cells.txt

#take alphabets to loop
foreach  b $a {
puts "$b\n"

if { [ exec cat cells.txt | awk ' $1 ~ /^$b/ ' ] } {

    foreach cell [exec cat ./cells.txt] {
    puts "$b \t $cell"
    }

}
```

The condition should check for first char in the file and give boolean. 
The error is:

> can't read "1": no such variable
>       while executing "exec cat cells.txt | awk ' $1 ~ /^$b/ ' "

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Tcl attaches *no special meaning at all* to the `'` character. It uses `{`…`}` (which nest better) for the same purpose. Your command:

```
exec cat cells.txt | awk ' $1 ~ /^$b/ '
```

should become:

```
exec cat cells.txt | awk { $1 ~ /^$b/ }
```

*Except…* you also want `$b` (but not `$1`) to be substituted in there. The easiest way to do that is with `format`:

```
exec cat cells.txt | awk [format { $1 ~ /^%s/ } $b]
```

It would be more optimal to omit the use of `cat` here:

```
exec awk [format { $1 ~ /^%s/ } $b] <cells.txt
```

---

You are aware that your whole script can be written in pure Tcl without any use of `exec`?

Comment: I'd suggest `exec awk -v "b=$b" {$1 ~ b} cells.txt` using awk's -v option to pass data from the outside into an awk variable.

Answer (score 0):

> can't read "1": no such variable

The (Tcl) error message is very informative. Tcl feels responsible for substituting a value of a Tcl variable `1` for `$1` (meant for awk as part of the awk script). This is due to improper quoting of your awk scriplet. At the same time, you want `$b` to be substituted for from within Tcl.

Turn `awk 'print $1 ~ /^$b/'` into `awk [string map [list @b@ $b] {{$1 ~ /^@b@/}}]`. Curly braces will preclude Tcl substitutions for `$1`, `@b@` will have already been substituted for before awk sees it thanks to `[string map]`.

```
exec cat cells.txt | awk [string map [list @b@ $b] {{$1 ~ /^@b@/}}]
```

That written, I fail to see why you are going back and forth between `grep`, `awk` etc. and Tcl. All of this could be done in Tcl alone.